# Prevent usage of wrong Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible

Imagine a server setup with Ansible with a production and a reference system/cluster and a separate server running Ansible (with ssh-keys). The different clusters are identified in two inventory files.

Every playbook usage will somehow look like `ansible-playbook -i production ...` or `ansible-playbook -i reference...`.

How do I prevent an accidental usage of the production inventory?

This could happen easily by either using an history entry in the shell or copy the command from some documentation.

---

Some ideas:

- As a start every documentation is referring to the `reference` inventory and is also using `--check`.
- Use two different Ansible instances and the common part is mirrored via Git. But this will result in some overhead.
- Prompt once for i.e. database passwords and use different on production and reference. But not all task/tags have such a password requirement.

---

Actually I'm looking for something like a master password when using a specific inventory? Or a task that is always executed even if a tag is used? What is the best practice here? Do you have other ideas? Or am I somehow totally wrong here and there is a better way for my scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Your production inventory could either be [vaulted](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) or even just include a vaulted file (which doesn't actually have to contain anything).

This will mean that when you attempt to run:

```
ansible-playbook -i production playbook.yml
```

It will fail with a message telling you to pass a vault password to it.

The vault password could be something simple such as "pr0duct10n" so it's entire purpose is to remind people that they are about to run it in production and so to think things through (much like how many people use a sudo password).